# How can I pass a block/proc and variable directly to a function?

Tags: ruby, variables, block, proc

I'm trying to learn about blocks and procs and I feel like this should be doable, but so far I haven't been successful.

**What I'd like:**

```
def main_action(generic_variable, block)
 generic_variable += 1 # I do more interesting stuff than this in my version
 yield(generic_variable)
end

main_action(3, {|num| num + 5 })
```

Or something similar.

The closest I found was http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html which seemed to require creating a passing method to send the blocks around:

```
class Monkey

  # Monkey.tell_ape { "ook!" }
  # ape: ook!
  #  => nil
  def self.tell_ape(&block)
    tell("ape", &block)
  end

  def self.tell(name, &block)
    puts "#{name}: #{block.call}"
  end
end
```

If I use the same passing method set up in my code I can get it to work, but it seems like unnecessary code. I tried calling `Monkey.tell("ape", { "ook!" })` directly, but got `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC`

Is it possible to send a variable and a block (or proc, I'm not picky) to a function in one call? Also, if you have time, what's going on above? Why doesn't that work?

Comment: What do you mean "in one call"?

Comment: in one function call - as in, not going through the `tell_ape` step, just doing it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing blocks and procs. A block is not a ruby object. You cannot pass it like

```
foo(args, block)
```

The only way to pass it is `foo(args){...}` or `foo(args) do ... end`. However, in method definition, you can receive a block, convert it into a proc, and accept it as one of its arguments like this:

```
def foo(args, &block)
  ...
end
```

On the other hand, You can pass a proc object as an argument like

```
foo(args, proc)
```

There are several ways to create a proc object, and a literal that is close to the block literal is the lambda: `->{...}`, but it is different from the block syntax `{...}`. Using this, you can do

```
foo(args, ->{...})
```

but not

```
foo(args, {...})
```

unless `{...}` is a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121748/863846) I was able to recreate the function in the question (`Monkey.tell`) using a block and proc. Here they are in case anyone else finds them useful!

```
def tell_proc(name, proc)
  puts "#{name}: #{proc.call('ook')}"
end
tell_proc('ape', ->(sound) { sound + "!" })

def tell_block(name, &block)
  puts "#{name}: #{block.call('ook')}"
end
tell_block('ape') {|sound| sound + "!" }
```